# Workers aren't showing up in ghash.io

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, cgminer, ghash.io

Im using cgminer 3.7.2 and I'm mining at ~77Mh/s in the ghash.io pool. I go to the worker list at the ghash website but nothing shows up. At the ghash main page it shows that I'm mining the blocks but it says 0 Gh/s

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll probably have more luck sending them a support request

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some accepted shares before any stats etc. will show.